# Product of two continuous functions - proof verification

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, solution-verification

I should show that given two real valued continuous functions $f$ and $g$, then $f\cdot g$ is continuous.

**My proof attempt:** Using the sequential definition of a continuous function, for any converging sequence $(a_n) \to a:$  $f(a_n) \to f(a)$ and $g(a_n) \to g(a)\space\space (1).$ Then, as $(f\cdot g)(a_n) = f(a_n)\cdot g(a_n)$, using $(1)$ and the fact that the product of two converging series converges (2) one obtains $f(a_n)\cdot g(a_n) \to f(a)\cdot g(a) = (f\cdot g)(a)$. Does this seem correct given that I have already proven (2)?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: You should  also mention their domain.  As it stands, the statement you are trying to prove does not make any sense. With domain in consideration, if $f$ and $g$ are continuous in that domain, then $f.g$ is continuous on the domain

Comment: @Koro I thought that would be obvious and implicitly conveyed when saying continuous, but I'm really just rephrasing the task here. Thanks for the remark however!